# Simple Time Pattern

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, pattern-recognition, local-time

I am given the times:

1:38, 2:44, 3:49, 4:55, ? , 7:05, 8:11, 9:16, 10:22, 11:27, 12:33

I am asked to find which time is missing and what the times signify?
Thanks!

Comment: It is, approximately, the times at when the minute hand of a clock is opposite the hour hand. But the one missing time is actually exact: 6:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a pretty simple pattern, the missing time should just be **6:00**.

For every time with an *odd* hour, add **1:06** to get the next term. For every time with an *even* hour, add **1:05** to get the next term!

$$h_n:m_n = h_{n-1}:m_{n-1} + \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \text{1:05 if }h_{n-1}\text{ is even} \\ \text{1:06 if }h_{n-1}\text{ is odd}
\end{array}\right.$$